# pyqtgraph ErrorBarItem doesn't draw a vertical line connecting horizontal error bars

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, pyqtgraph, errorbar

Consider following code:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np

pg.setConfigOptions(antialias=True)

yPoints = np.array([4.2315e-12, 5.0400e-12, 4.7119e-12, 5.0892e-12,])
xPoints = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
errors = np.array([2.9131e-13, 3.452e-13, 3.3071e-13, 3.762e-13 + 3e-13])

plt = pg.plot()
errorBarItem = pg.ErrorBarItem(x=xPoints, y=yPoints,  top=errors, bottom=errors, beam=0.2)
plt.addItem(errorBarItem)
plt.plot(xPoints, yPoints, symbol='o', pen={'color': 0.8, 'width': 2})

## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode or using pyside.
if __name__ == '__main__':
  import sys
  if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
    QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

which plots:

[image]

It appears the vertical line connecting horizontal error bars is not drawn below certain range (?).

is there a way to force ErrorBarItem to draw that vertical line, always? how to walk around it?

Answer (score 2):

This looks very much like a bug and should be reported on [the issues page](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/issues). EDIT: nm, I see that you already [posted there](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/issues/1457) and that the same conclusion as mince was reached there.

It looks like the bars are not drawn for error values under 5e-13. You can see that if you multiply your errors by 10, or even 2, then the bars appear.

For the moment, I would suggest multiplying both your y-values and error by 1e12 and write in the label that the values are in pico-units(?)